# Azure default Service Definition values

Tags: wcf, service, azure

I noticed that it is not possible to add values to settings elements in the Service Definition file (.csdef). Currently, I define the values in every Service Configuration File (.cscfg).

However, since the values are 99.9% the same, I would like to be able to remove the explicit definition of the values in every configuration file and rely on default values, while maintaining the ability to overwrite the values in specific environments.

What's the best way to implement the above? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The approach I've used is to create my own configuration provider that can set defaults when requested values are not available. Using such a provider also allows me to easily remove built in dependencies on the service configuration should I have a need for multi-platform deployment.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Brent said, if you still are stuck to the Azure specific, do not edit the values in the file itself, but rather use the Visual Studio properties UI for the role:

[image: Property settings]

You see, the properties which are common to all configurations you can edit. And the ones that are configuration specific you see "Select Configuration". However, I personally would have been more satisfied if the approach for having different settings was [just like](http://blogs.staykov.net/2011/06/windows-azure-configuration-settings.html) the [web.config transformations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326.aspx).